Confusion about creating paclet documentation
I have a paclet for which I used the DocumentationTools palette to build documentation. This palette created a directory structure Documentation/English/... with my unbuild documentation notebooks. When I run PacletDocumentationBuild on the paclet directory, a new directory structure build/Anyonica/Documentation/English/... is created in the paclet directory that contains the proper documentation notebooks.
However, none of the documentation appears when searching for it in the documentation centre search bar.
My package does appear under the Installed Add-Ons section at the bottom of the main page of the documentation center, but when I click to open the documentation for the package I only get a non-build notebook.
When I look at, e.g., a package like QMRITools I see that there is no build directory and all the proper documentation resides in the Documentation directory.
I could back up my unbuild documentation notebooks and move all the build ones to the Documentation directory. The thing that bothers me is that both the Documentation and build directories were created by default by the PacletTools so I would find it strange if I would now have to move all my documentation manually to 'fix' something that wolfram created by default.
Am I using the DocumentationTools palette in the wrong manner? If so, how should one use
this pallet correctly to have searchable build documentation appear in the documentation center?
My version of Mathematica is 14.1

In order to make the available documentation available, you need to use PacletTools`PacletBuild to create a .paclet file of your code. You can then use PacletInstall on that file to install the paclet and integrate its documentation.
